# Full text search error in production but not staging

Tags: google-app-engine, full-text-search

In google app engine, I'm running a full text search with the exact same code in production as staging. The only difference is data in the database.

The staging environment runs perfectly, but the production env. gives me the following error:

```
  File "<mydir>/mycode.py", line 51, in get
    search_result = lnp_index.search(query)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/datastore/datastore_rpc.py", line 105, in positional_wrapper
    return wrapped(*args, **kwds)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/api/search/search.py", line 3676, in search
    return self.search_async(query, deadline=deadline, **kwargs).get_result()
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/api/search/search.py", line 262, in get_result
    return self._get_result_hook()
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/api/search/search.py", line 3690, in hook
    _CheckStatus(response.status())
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/api/search/search.py", line 517, in _CheckStatus
    raise _ERROR_MAP[status.code()](status.error_detail())
InvalidRequest: Failed to execute search request "4597385989193728"
```

My code that calls the search looks like this:

```
query_str = self.request.get('query') or self.request.get('did')
limit = int(self.request.get('limit', 50))
prev_cursor = self.request.get('cursor', None)
expr_list = [
    fts.SortExpression(expression='created_date',
                       default_value=1,
                       direction=fts.SortExpression.DESCENDING),
]
sort_opts = fts.SortOptions(expressions=expr_list, limit=limit)
cursor_obj = fts.Cursor(web_safe_string=prev_cursor) if prev_cursor and prev_cursor != "None" else fts.Cursor()
query_options = fts.QueryOptions(limit=limit, cursor=cursor_obj, sort_options=sort_opts)
lnp_index = fts.Index(name=constants.FTS_LNP_INDEX)
query = fts.Query(query_string=full_query_str, options=query_options)
search_result = lnp_index.search(query)
```

And the cursor is generated like this and sent off to the web (which sends it back in the params):

```
cursor = search_result.cursor.web_safe_string if search_result.cursor else None
```

What could be causing this?

Comment: Please show the code with which you configure the index and build the query -- certain restrictions on the "real" (production) API may not be reproduced with 100% accuracy on the "simulated" (local) one, but it's impossible to tell without seeing a small, stand-alone, complete example.

Comment: I just added the updates with my specific code. Also, the search fails whether it's supposed to return hundreds of items or just 1 item

Comment: in your code, I see `full_query_str` mentioned just once (it's never bound to a value but there's an attempt to use its value) so you may have posted only part of your code (your code as posted should 500 with a `NameError`). Besides this, I'd add one or more `logging.info` calls showing all the variables you do assign and edit your Q to show us what the logs have to say (on your local dev, vs, in production).

Comment: @sg Did you figure out the solution to this ? or why the problem was being triggered.. I'm facing the same issue not will all queries but with some..